# Google Maps API - place_changed Listener Firing On Second Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

JS

```
var location_input = document.getElementById('location');
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(location_input);

google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function(){
  alert('here');
  console.log('here');
});
```

HTML

```
{{Form::input('text', 'location', null, ['id' => 'location', 'class' => 'form-control']) }}

@section('after-scripts')
    {!! Html::script('PATH_TO_SCRIPT.js') !!}
@endsection
```

The event is firing if I arrow down the results and press enter. It also works if I click an Item from the list, click back into the input box, and click the same item again.

The issue I am having is the event should be firing on the first click of an item being selected and not the second.

Comment: Perhaps a fiddle would be nice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a silly mistake on my end. I was using the Autocomplete method on the same text field in a different location from where I was working with the code mentioned in the question. Once I removed the 2nd Autocomplete everything started working as expected.

It's amazing what a little sleep can do.